# Junit for spring boot global exception

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to cover the exception code in the get method of the DelController class, but it is not calling the DelIntakeGlobalException.

```
@RestController
public class DelController{
@GetMapping("/getId")
public ResponseEntity<?> get(@PathVariable String intakeNumber){

try{
Integer.parseInt(intakeNumber);
return new ResponseEntity<>("success",HttpStatus.OK);

}catch(NumberFormatException e){

throw new DelIntakeGlobalException("intakeNumber is invalid");
}
}
}


@ControllerAdvice
public class DelIntakeExceptionHandler{
@ExceptionHandler(DelIntakeGlobalException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleException(DelIntakeGlobalException exp, ServletWebRequest req){

return new ResponseEntity<>(exp.getMessage(),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

}
}

@Runwith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class controllerTest{

@InjectMocks
DelController controller;

@Test
public getTest(){

assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,controller.get("123po").getStatusCode());
}

}
```

I could not find a solution for this. Could you please help on how to handle this scenario? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to test behavior of Spring using spring beans (Controller, Advice) but your test is not starting the spring context. So basically your test does not know that DelIntakeExceptionHandler is supposed to handle the exception.
In your case you can or just test exception thrown

```
@Test(expected=DelIntakeGlobalException.class)
public getTest(){

controller.get("123po");
assertFail();
}
```

Or start spring context within test annotating test with  @SpringBootTest and to have even better simulation of the controller using [MockMVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/).
so sth like

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestClass{

@Test
public getTest(){
this.mockMvc.perform(get("/getId/123po")))
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()));
}
}
```